# Bug in the physics profile page

Tags: bug, profile-page

I think there is an error in the  physics profile page. The *about me* section does not fit. I already tried to zoom, but that didn't help. Please see the picture below for clarification.

[image]

Comment: @PatrickHofman It also happens on Electrical Engineering.